# Get location of element using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, specflow

I cannot get the location of the element. This is what i have so far
I have defined the element

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "column-a")] 
private IWebElement _columnA;
private string [] startLoc;
private string [] endLoc;
```

Then within the method I have:

```
startLoc[0] = _columnA.Location.X.ToString() + " " + _columnA.Location.Y.ToString();
```

Upon runtime, I get an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in framework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot use a string array that is not instantiated:

```
// Don't do this:
string[] foo;
foo[0] = "bar";     // throws System.NullReferenceException
```

To initialize an array, use the string array initializer:

```
var foo = new string[1]; // string array with 1 empty element
foo[0] = "bar";
```

But in C# it is more elegant to use [Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx). Maybe you can redesign your code and use a `List<string>`.